# how do i join 2 seperate joins in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

im learning postgres joins and im stuck at this problem.
Basically im trying to join two table which are derived by two joins but i get the following error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "join"

LINE 3:  inner join on mov1.genre_id = mov2.genre_id

```
select *
from(
    (select 
        id, genre_id
    from
        movie inner join in_genre on movie.id = in_genre.movie_id 
        where movie.id = 1375666) as mov1

    inner join on mov1.genre_id = mov2.genre_id

    (select 
        id, genre_id
    from
        movie inner join in_genre on movie.id = in_genre.movie_id 
        where movie.id = 0278504) as mov2
)
```

Comment: put inner join on mov1.genre_id = mov2.genre_id after mov2 is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's easy for you to work with "table expressions" (aka "derived tables" or "inline views") then go for it.

However, if they become too complex, CTEs (Common Table Expressions) come to the rescue. You can build each table expression separately, and then you can join them. This way you build your query, step by step.

For example:

```
with
mov1 as ( -- declaring the first table expression "mov1"
  select 
    id, genre_id
  from movie
  inner join in_genre on movie.id = in_genre.movie_id 
  where movie.id = 1375666
),
mov2 as ( -- declaring the second table expression "mov2"
  select 
    id, genre_id
  from movie
  inner join in_genre on movie.id = in_genre.movie_id 
  where movie.id = 0278504
)
select * -- finally the main SELECT looks a lot simpler
from mov1
join mov2 on mov1.genre_id = mov2.genre_id
```

As a side note, the CTEs can be reused multiple times in the query, by any following CTE or the main query.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the join is at the end

```
select *
from 
    (select 
        id, genre_id
    from
        movie inner join in_genre on movie.id = in_genre.movie_id 
        where movie.id = 1375666) as mov1

    inner join 

    (select 
        id, genre_id
    from
        movie inner join in_genre on movie.id = in_genre.movie_id 
        where movie.id = 0278504) as mov2
 on mov1.genre_id = mov2.genre_id
```